# JDBC Query vs JPA Query Performance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am having some issues related with performance while reading thousands of records from the database. I noticed that a pure JDBC query is much more faster that a JPA Native query.

Here is the query

```
select ID, COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D, COL_E, COL_F from MY_SUPER_VIEW_V v 
where 1=1 
and v.ID in (:idList)
and v.DATE_FROM <= :date
and v.DATE_TILL >= :date;
```

This query returns around 38.000 records.

The in idList has more than 1000 records and because I am using an Oracle DB it needs to be split in n queries.

Further i have a method that converts the Object[] result to my `List<Entity>`.

In order to understand the performance issue i created a pure JDBC query and a JPA Native query respectively to compare the results.

Here are the timings.

```
################ getScoresPureJDBCWithListIds ################
List of Ids retrieved. It took: 00:00:00.096 to execute query on DB using JDBC
It took: 00:00:01.180 to execute query on DB using JDBC query
Creating 24206 Scores records from DB result It took: 00:00:04.440
It took: 00:00:01.038 to execute query on DB using JDBC query
Creating 14445 Scores records from DB result It took: 00:00:04.307
################ getScoresJPANativeQueryWithListIds ################
It took: 00:06:09.450 to execute query on DB using JPA Native query
Creating 24206 Scores records from DB result It took: 00:00:00.009
It took: 00:04:04.879 to execute query on DB using JPA Native query
Creating 14445 Scores records from DB result It took: 00:00:00.007
```

**With Hibernate analytics**

```
################ USING FETCH_SIZE: 2000 ################
################ getScoresPureJDBCWithListIds ################
List of <elements> retrieved. It took: 00:00:00.296 to execute query on DB using JDBC
It took: 00:00:11.940 to execute query on DB using JDBC query
Creating 24206 records from DB result It took: 00:00:02.670
It took: 00:00:13.570 to execute query on DB using JDBC query
Creating 14445 records from DB result It took: 00:00:02.553

################ getScoresJDBCTemplateWithListIds ################
    List of <elements> retrieved. It took: 00:00:00.087 to execute query on DB using JDBC
    Creating 24206 records from DB result It took: 00:00:04.063
    Creating 14445 records from DB result It took: 00:00:04.064
    ################ getScoresJPANativeQueryAsApplication with hint fetch size 2000 ################
    2020-04-22 09:36:30.830  INFO 13262 --- [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
        1232369 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
        0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
        1448702 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
        3992364 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
    }
    List of <ids> retrieved. It took: 00:00:00.261 to execute query on DB using JDBC
    2020-04-22 09:47:23.739  INFO 13262 --- [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
        73670 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
        0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
        805772 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
        651947762290 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements; ==> 10 minutes
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
    }
    It took: 00:10:52.898 to execute query on DB using JPA Native query
    Creating 24206 records from DB result It took: 00:00:00.018
    2020-04-22 09:56:00.792  INFO 13262 --- [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
        2758010 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
        0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
        3096653 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
        516148003151 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
    }
    It took: 00:08:37.032 to execute query on DB using JPA Native query
    Creating 14445 records from DB result It took: 00:00:00.006
```

For the JDBC query I can see 1) that executing the query is quite fast, but 2) processing each ResultSet element in a loop takes the most of the time 00:09 seconds int total

On the other for the JPA Native query 1) executing the query by calling the query.getResultList() method takes a lot of time 10:14 seconds on the other hand 2) processing each result is quite fast here. Analytics shows that a huge amount of time is spent on executing 1 JDBC statement. Even with FETCH_SIZE = 2000 nothing changed significantly.

**Why JPA Native is quite slow when compare with pure JDBC?** Would it be the type conversions? In my case I am talking about varchar2 and numbers. I was expecting identical results to JDBC. but from 8 seconds to 10mins its a lot.

**What can I do to improve the JPA Native query?**

Comment: `v.ID in (:idList)` this is very suspicious. What do you pass in the `:idList` in the *JDBC* call? A comma separated list of values?

Comment: Also the very first thing to verify, if both aproaches use the same (and appropriate) value of the *fetch size*.

Comment: in the JDBC case i am setting the parameters normally scoresPreparedStatement.setLong(i+3, partition.get(i)) but on the query i had to transform it on ID in (?, ?, ?, ?, ........, ?)

Comment: the fetch_size actualy is not set, only batch_size=50. What is the default value? what is the best value to set? I just red that 20 or 500 have not much difference

Comment: You should start by setting Hibernate to log the SQL it's issuing and comparing it.

Comment: setting spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=500 apparently had not much or none effect on the reult time. it is still taking around 10minutes

Comment: After rereading your question, this is NO GO neither for JPA nor for JDBC. IN list was designed to address *few* IDs not 24K. sql_trace the JPA statement and you will see tons of ORs connecting the IN list predicates, which aparently would confuse the optimizer. The right approach is to find a solution withoup long IN lists.

Comment: Remember that your "jpa operations" takes hydration/dehydration" into account - so its not just plain jdbc call.

Comment: @ Marmite Bomber The inList "just" have 1600 elements (which means 2 queries in Oracle, 1 with 1000 and another with 600). The 24k that you see there is the number of records on the result.

Comment: Something that migh not be clear is that the query returns 37K results

Comment: Would it be possible to see the generated SQL statement?

Comment: Just posting the first query. the 2nd is exactly the same but wih less ids in the in clause. The first query the in clause takes 1000 elems, and the 2nd query 615 elements: Hibernate: SELECT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D, COL_E, COL_F, COL_G, COL_H FROM TABLE_A WHERE COL_A in (?, ?, ?, ... ?, ?, ?) AND (DATE_FROM <= ? AND DATE_TILL >= ?)

Again JDBC deals well with it. Why internally Hibernate is taking a huge amount of time when pure jdbc takes 8seconds :(

Comment: Is Hibernate a proper tool to be used when processing dozen or even hundred of thounsands of records?

Comment: Please post your *Hibernate version*, *Oracle Version*, the definition of the *view* along with underlining *tables and idices* and the *code snippets* that are you are comparing.  Hibernate is *ORM tool for OLTP*; on-line transactions are typically small...

Comment: We are using spring-boo version 2.1.1.RELEASE and the respective <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> dependency. Oracle driver: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Regarding views, i cannot share, but i can guarantee that are very simple, and there is an index with all the columns that are being used to filter results on the where clause.

Comment: The oracle driver is the same used on the JDBC connection or even on the SpringJDBCTemplate. And both of them have um very quick responses. My impression is that Hibernate is fetching one by one result, even having FETCH_SIZE = 2000. But i cannot confirm that

Comment: What do you mean by "Hibernate is ORM tool for OLTP; on-line transactions are typically small"? What should it be taken in consideration with that?

Comment: Formulated my thoughts in an answer

Answer (score 5):

You seem to compare two different queries, quite possibly resulting in the database coming up with different query plans.

There are lots of ways to investigate the problem but none of those are available to us because you don't provide a minimal reproducible example. I'll therefore suggest some options for you to investigate this yourself:

- Enable debug logging for your Java application including Hibernate and Oracle JDBC driver as explained in their documentation
- Watch where the delay is coming from, is it the database, the network, or your Java application? If in doubt check the network traffic with Wireshark on both sides of the connection or check Oracles database statistics on slow/heavy queries before and after the problematic queries
- If the problem is a slow database make sure your query parameters have matching types with your database index
- If you are sure the network and database are not causing the issue and debug logging doesn't help you further try using advanced tools like a cpu profiler with e.g. JVisualVM
- If you're still having problems maybe you have some extreme memory problem like to little system memory causing swapping or very frequent Full Garbage Collection which you can see from Garbage Collection logging

Answer (score 3):

Please note, that if you want to compare two concepts you must try to isolate the main feature and get rid of other factors, that may disturb the result.

So to see if the JDBC query and JPA native query difference in behaviour I'd propose following scenario:

- use only *one* query with the 1000 element list
- use a *plain table* instead of a view

Here a simple setup to validate a performance. The table has 50 rows for each `GRP_ID` resulting in getting 50K rows for 1000 keys (see below the script to setup the table)

```
List params = (13001L..14000L)
def query = session.createNativeQuery("select * from tab where grp_id in (:paramsList) ")
query.setFetchSize(2000)
query.setParameterList("paramsList", params);
result = query.getResultList();
```

Sample run shows this result

```
 got 50000 rows in 1.388 seconds
```

So I thing there is no need to repeat the test with plain JDBC you will see a comparable result.

What is more interesting is to repeat the run and *remove* the line

```
query.setFetchSize(2000)
```

which will effectively reset the fetch size to the default (was 20 in my case), the result for the same data is

```
 got 50000 rows in 1 minutes, 0.903 seconds
```

**1)** So the fetch size is the most probable explanation of the observed behaviour. The important thing is to check, if the JDBC drive got the right value and uses it - in doubt you must use the 10046 trace to see what fetch size uses the database. But for me the above statement worked perfectly.

**2)** There is no substantial difference between a native JPA query and a manually written JDBC execute + fetch of a prepared statement that would explain your observation. Both perform *execute of the statement in the database* followed by a number of *fetches* - the count depend on the used *fetch size*

**3)** Of course the *view* can also have influence, but it will be a difference in the *query* - not betwen the *JDBC v. JPA*.

**4)** You didn't mention it, so I'm not going in details here and assume your view doesn't contain any `CLOB` columns. This could of course play a role.

**5)** The last point is in your mention of *two queries* - do you use two independent queries or one query whith `OR` concatenated IN list? You din not provide details so it's hard to comment. Anyway two independent queries should have no influence.

Having said that one word of warning.

The limitation of the IN list count has its purpose. It is acceptable for *an ad Hoc script* to use a large IN list selection, but for a regular running query this could be a
*parsing problem*. Why?

You use a bind variables to be able to consider the following queries as a single statement (that is parsed only once)

```
select * from tab where ID = 1
select * from tab where ID = 2
```

which leads to

```
select * from tab where ID = ?
```

But following two queries (with different length of the IN list) *remains different and must be each extra parsed*

```
select * from tab where ID in ( ? )
select * from tab where ID in ( ?, ? )
```

So re-think if for your purpose with 30K rows+ the Hibernate is the best option.

Hibernate was designed to elegantly get gid of the need of *using SQL* which is by majority of developers considered a *cool think* (contrary to the majority of the DB people that have an opposite meaning;).

This concept works fine, the simple the use case is the better. On the other side for *batch processing* it is sometimes better to approach it directly with SQL.

Test data:

```
create table tab as 
select 
rownum id,
trunc(rownum /  50) +1 grp_id,
rpad('x',100,'y') pad
from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
create index idx on tab(grp_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is generally faster then JPA, but in JPA you can benefit from caching and this way get better performance.

I dont know the purpose of this query and how is used (reporting?), but you should consider to use different criteria then just list of so many ids. I doubt some user have chosen 1000+ ids manually, so i guess they are chosen batch by some other criteria. Try to use this creatia instead.

Comment: The argument of *caching* is not much valid in this compare, as usualy if you program with JDBC and you have a full controll of the queries you *do not ask repeatedly for the same data from the database*  - a use case where the *caching shine*.